# ownCloud migration failed with upgrade from 10.0.0.4 to 10.1.0

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, owncloud, mysql5

After migrating ownCloud to another server, I am attempting to run an update. When running `occ upgrade`, the the upgrade ends with the following error message:

```
2019-04-29T22:23:22+00:00 Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException: The table with name 'owncloud.oc_persistent_locks' already exists.
2019-04-29T22:23:22+00:00 Update failed
```

Any tips on the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are pending issues in OwnCloud with using shared hosters and the usage of foreign keys. [This issue comment](https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/34598#issuecomment-533783868) mentions a possible point you could check.